# Split a String into smaller Strings. Random Length of String assumed.

Tags: c++, string, char

I have a string (not necessarily divisible by 8) of random length.

I now want to convert every 8 characters into a string. I am somehow clueless about the end of this string. I don't know how to handle the last zeros and ones.

This should be totally reversable.

I am programming in Visual Studio and C++.

Do you have any suggestions? I hope i expressed myself clearly. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, do you want an array with the consecutive 8-character substrings of this string?

Comment: You might start grouping by 8 (8 bit = 1 byte, one ASCII character or utf-8 encoded one) and then see what's left. Perhaps padding the remaining with zeros on the MSB (most significant bits). I don't know what you're dealing with..

Comment: chars is a primitive data type, what you're asking for seems like a string. Unless you actually want single chars, or you're looking for an array of chars, which then i'd question why, because that IS a String.

Comment: Iterate through the string and use a counter. Increment the counter by 1 each time. Append each character to a new string. When the counter gets to 8, you have the first string. Reset the character counter to 0. Proceed in the same way and create a new string each time the counter reaches 8.

Comment: No, you didn't express yourself very well.  You say you want to convert 8 chars into a "string", but I suspect you want each 8 chars converted into a byte -- a character Boolean to binary conversion.

Comment: I've wrote you a solution. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Find the length, divide by 8 and enter the last into array of size of remainder. E.g if you have array of length 60 then when you divide you get 7, enter these into array of 8 and create one of size remainder which is 4 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
string whole = "01001010101010101000011110101001000101000010000";
string pieces[whole.length()/8];

for(int i = 0; i< whole.length()/8; i++)
    pieces[i] = like.substr(i*8,8);
```

and to see whats in it?

```
for(int i = 0; i < whole.length()/8; i++)
    cout << "\r\n" + pieces[i] + "\r\n";
```